# How to Trace my Network's Steps

Tags: wireless, networking, login, kvm-virtualization, logging

Question (concise version):

Where in my log files would I find information regarding the networking steps executed between the time I have left the login screen and the time I have landed comfortably at my desktop screen?

```
$ uname -a
Linux schmo 3.2.0-31-generic-pae #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:39:45 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

---

Question (longer version with more than one clause):

Who, or what daemon, or which scripts are responsible for setting up my network settings at login?  I have found that several attempts to modify `/etc/network/interfaces` either go ignored or end in a non-functioning setup, but that the two-line original loopback version works fine.  I want to know where the action is actually happening.

What `.conf`'s and `bash` scripts should I pepper with echo-and-dump statements, or what environment variables should I be aware of and set, if the current level of feedback in the currently-available log files is not of a resolution high enough to catch the network changes being performed during login?

Motivation (at least one of them):

How would I go about telling my computer to establish a wireless bridge *after* my wireless network adapter is up and running, which itself seems to occur only *after* I log in, sometimes completing after I have already clicked on Firefox but before I remember to look for the wifi status icon, argh.

What I've done so far:

- SUCCESSFULLY added a VM running precise server i686 to my precise desktop i686 using KVM
- SUCCESSFULLY updated, upgraded, and added to the packages on the VM through the bridge setup suggested at http://devilsworkshop.org/tutorial/create-virtual-machineos-ubuntu-1204-kvm/59576/, and following the course of https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html, while ssh'd from my desktop.  **This implies the bridge was working**, if only for one session.  My guess is that between the time I set up my `/etc/network/interfaces` file and the time I no longer had internet access through my VM, the changes I (or KVM, or someone) made to my configuration files had propagated only partially through my system(s) from boot to boot and restart to restart, whatever that means.
- UNSUCCESSFULLY tried to resurrect VM internet access by adding wlan0 to `/etc/network/interfaces` in various forms, including installing `wpa_supplicant`.
- RECEIVED AN ERROR from `wpa_supplicant` which I believe I was able to trace back to the fact that wpa services are mysteriously already running each time I restart networking.  This led me to the discovery that...
- AVAHI WILL NOT STAY DEAD due to being respawned by process #1 ; `avahi` then runs other stuff, and may be responsible for the normally satisfying, but now vexing, behavior of my wireless connection coming alive each time I log in (or not doing so, if I try to modify `/etc/network/interfaces`).

More details are available; just tell me what you'd like.  I am playing a game of Chutes-and-Ladders with the heaps of knowledge I have learned from trying what I have so far, and the vast chasms of ignorance about even basic terms and SOP that keep me from putting things together.

I have looked at this [help.ubuntu.com page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking). Note the part about wireless bridging.  I have my reasons for ignoring this caveat for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

As to the short question (and note the cmd #'s I added, starting from 0):

```
0) dmesg | grep wlan0
```

will give timestamps for system events (since your most recent boot) regarding your wireless router.  Note that some people's devices may be called 'eth0' or another variant besides 'wlan0', depending on kernel, device management, and other configuration settings beyond this respondent's grasp.

Next, follow the `grep` chain.  When in doubt, look everywhere you can think of.  Everywhere *I* could think of was `/etc` and `/var/log`:

- `/etc` contains configuration files and scripts that define practically all of your services' behavior, no exaggeration.
- `/var/log` is the standard location for these services to dump their outputs for logging, whether in a form easily identifiable to human eyes or not.

NOTE: Recursively `grep`'ing `/` can't hurt on current systems with memory, cpu time, and disk space to spare.  Familiarize yourself with coordinated bio breaks and ctrl-C, it could take a while.  Also look into redirecting output to a file, so you can read it later.  DO NOT `sudo grep` unless you really know what lies beneath those system directories `grep` denies you.  Those system directories quickly become redundant, recursive, overly verbose, non-text, and myriad.

I got copious information from the following greps:

```
1) grep "wlan0" -R /var/log 2>/dev/null
```

This `grep` will spit out all the lines I got from `dmesg` *plus* some things `dmesg` does not show - like calling process names for each timestamp or process id, lines from previous boots, the names of files I didn't even know about like `/var/log/udev`...

An aside: `udev` does frickin' everything!

That `grep -R` is going to need some deconstruction, however.  To relate it immediately to the initial `grep` statement, take any timestamp from `dmesg` (the numbers in brackets) and try

```
2) grep "\[ 8529.265562\]" -A 10 /var/log/syslog 2>/dev/null
```

where you replace my timestamp with whatever timestamp you happen to be interested in.  NOTE:  To be as noob-unfriendly as possible, the shell-and-regex people require you to add those *backslashes* to the brackets, i.e. `\[` and `\]`, don't simply copy-and-paste.  Why?  Barriers to entry, that's why.  Read up on [grep and regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep).

The above `grep -A` should give you the line from `dmesg` you were expecting (which also got logged in /var/log/syslog with the rest) and its 10 succeeding entries:

```
$ grep "\[11766.363095\]" /var/log/syslog -A 10 2>/dev/null
Oct 19 08:57:40 mitzvah kernel: [11766.363095] wlan0: authenticate with 12:34:56:78:9a:bc (try 1)
Oct 19 08:57:40 mitzvah kernel: [11766.365183] wlan0: authenticated
Oct 19 08:57:40 mitzvah NetworkManager[1261]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct 19 08:57:41 mitzvah kernel: [11766.638899] wlan0: associate with 12:34:56:78:9a:bc (try 1)
Oct 19 08:57:41 mitzvah kernel: [11766.641406] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 12:34:56:78:9a:bc (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 19 08:57:41 mitzvah kernel: [11766.641411] wlan0: associated
Oct 19 08:57:41 mitzvah wpa_supplicant[1866]: Associated with 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
Oct 19 08:57:41 mitzvah kernel: [11766.646978] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Oct 19 08:57:41 mitzvah NetworkManager[1261]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Oct 19 08:57:42 mitzvah NetworkManager[1261]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Oct 19 08:57:42 mitzvah wpa_supplicant[1866]: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 12:34:56:78:9a:bc [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
```

Hey look!  there's wpa_supplicant, in line 6.  It's process id was 1866 at the time.  And there's another process that sounds network-manager-like, called NetworkManager.  That's the culprit I was looking for that keeps waving its magic wand at my network setup.

This is not the end, of course.  I googled NetworkManager ; I re`grep`'ed the log and /etc directories on wpa_client armed with slightly more info.  When my network was least well and I could not figure out how NetworkManager knew what it did behind my back, I found solice in the following command:

```
3) grep wlan0 -R /etc
...
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules:SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="12:34:56:78:9a:bc", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
...
```

This `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file holds information about my less-than-permanent devices over from session to session, I think.  This would be how various services are able to seem like they know what it is you're plugging and unplugging from time to time ; they do know, since somebody's recording it.

All of this, just for info.  My main motivation is unsatisfied: I have yet to get my wlan0 up from boot.  Here's to hoping.

```
Linux - Because I like banging my head against walls.
```

Comment: Some hopefully *cross-fingers* useful links for Network Manager: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager0.7 (note out-of-date warning)

Comment: Also - to discover that, e.g. `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` contains information pertinent to this topic, you will have to use `sudo grep` (selectively).  Argh.  "Look where you're supposed to look."  "Where's that?"  "Somewhere you're not supposed to look."  "Where's that?"

Comment: Another maybe-useful link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing  BUT note that I found this when I googled for info about the IPv4 settings option "Shared to other computers" ; I am shaky about the terminology "ad hoc" - is it synonymous with this IPv4 option in the network manager app?

Comment: Here's something on wifi "master" mode, which differs from "managed" and "ad hoc" (but is similar to "wds") in that it allows (or disallows?) the abuse of MAC addresses by the wireless card.  I may soon know what that means! https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode

Comment: More sideways news: proxy ARP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP  This may be the (only) way to go for my desired setup.

Comment: "The Open Systems Interconnection (OSI) model (ISO/IEC 7498-1) is a product of the Open Systems Interconnection effort at the International Organization for Standardization." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model  I *really* feel the need to point out that the above statement effectively uses ISO, OSI, and IOS in the same sentence.  Lord, tell me there's a rabbit at the end of this hole.